# Unix: Combine PDF -files and images into PDF -file?

Tags: image, macos, unix, pdf

My friend is asking this question, he is using Mac and cannot get PdfLatex working (having no dev CD, related [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/compiling-latex-in-apple-products-is-something-like-pdflatex-around)). Anyway my first idea:

> - $ pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf **[only pdfs]**
> - $ convert 1.png 2.png myfile.pdf **[only images]**

Now I don't know without LaTex or iPad's Notes Plus how to combine images and PDF -files. So how can I combine pdf -files and images in Unix?

Comment: Thank you hhh! The answer is here in Apple default commandline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778635/merging-png-images-into-one-pdf-file-in-unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a loop, identifying PDF and images, and converting images to PDF with ImageMagick. When you're done, you assemble it all with pdftk.

This is a Bash-only script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Convert arguments into list
N=0
for file in $*; do
        files[$N]=$file
        N=$[ $N + 1 ]
done
# Last element of list is our destination filename
N=$[ $N - 1 ]
LAST=$files[$N]
unset files[$N]
N=$[ $N - 1 ]
# Check all files in the input array, converting image types
T=0
for i in $( seq 0 $N ); do
        file=${files[$i]}
        case ${file##*.} in
                jpg|png|gif|tif)
                        temp="tmpfile.$T.pdf"
                        convert $file $temp
                        tmp[$T]=$temp
                        uses[$i]=$temp
                        T=$[ $T + 1 ]
                        # Or also: tmp=("${tmp[@]}" "$temp")
                ;;
                pdf)
                        uses[$i]=$file
                ;;
        esac
done
# Now assemble PDF files
pdftk ${uses[@]} cat output $LAST
# Destroy all temporary file names. Disabled because you never know :-)
echo "I would remove ${tmp[@]}"
# rm ${tmp[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am gathering here some info.

**Unix Commandline**

> 1. More about Pdftk [here](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/).
> 2. [Merging png images into one pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778635/merging-png-images-into-one-pdf-file-in-unix)
> 3. [Combine all files in a folder as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156126/combine-all-files-in-a-folder-as-pdf)

**Mac**

> Because the moderator in Apple SE removed the useful thread *"Merge PDF files and images to single PDF file in Mac?"*
>   [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65327/merge-pdf-files-and-images-to-single-pdf-file-in-mac)
>   -- I collect the tips here for Mac -- sorry but the moderator is very intolerant about collecting Newbie -things.
>
> > 1. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/what-software-is-available-preferably-free-to-create-and-edit-pdf-files-on-mac
> > 2. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-can-i-combine-two-pdfs-in-preview
> > 3. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11163/how-do-i-combine-two-or-more-images-to-get-a-single-pdf-file
> > 4. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69659/ipad-pdf-software-to-edit-merge-annotate-etc-well-pdf-documents-like-in-deskto